# Unable to setup 100% height in react css

Tags: css, reactjs

Im doing a react app that prints multiple "elements" like if it was some sort of calendar.
But im trying to setup a background-color so it will cover the background behind all the cubes, but seems impossible to do.

I basically have this

Calendario.jsx

```
 render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <CalendarGrid weeks={this.getLivedWeeks()}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

CalendarGrid.jsx

```
    render() {
    let rows = []
    for (let i = 0; i<this.props.weeks;i++){
      rows.push(<CalendarFields key={i} />)
    }
    return <h1>{rows}</h1>

  }
```

Then in calendario.css

I've applied this

```
.container{
    background-color:yellow;
    height:100%;
}
```

But it wont display anything. Meanwhile if I put

```
 .container{
        background-color:yellow;
        height:100vh;
    }
```

It works just as I want it, but it only covers the 100vh , but my screen happens to take more than 100vh since I have to scroll down, so thats not the solution.

I dont understand why height: 100% wont work there

This is how it happens to looks with 100vh

[image: 100vh result]

Comment: try adding overflow:hidden in .container class

Comment: @ShirishMaharjan that works, do you mind giving a brief explanation of why?

Comment: use min-height instead of height

Comment: @TemaniAfif it doesnt

Comment: while keeping 100vh of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now in your example the div contains only floated elements. This makes it collapse to a height of 0px. The adjacent calendar Grid will appear to the left/right of the floated div because they are considered as normal floated elements.

Now declaring overflow establishes a new block formatting context, which makes the div contains its children. Suddenly the div "reappears", not having size 0px anymore. The calendar grid is getting pushed to the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

> When dealing with widths, the % unit is more suitable. With heights,
>   the vh unit is better.

**Key Differences----**

**`height: 100vh`** = 100% of the viewport height

**`height: 100%`** = 100% of the parent's element height

That's why you need to add height: 100% on html and body, as they don't have a size by default

Something you have to know : if you use % for vertical margin or padding, % will be calculated on the width of the parent element, not the height.

Tip : try using vh and vw units for font size :) I like this one (not supported in some browsers I know) : `font-size: calc(.5vh + .5vw);` (for example)

[% vs vh](https://css-tricks.com/the-lengths-of-css/)